# How do I automatically create an array of objects (the number of which is determined by user input)

Tags: java, object, graph, processing

I am writing a program where I am making a dynamic bar graph which processing reads in from Arduino. From the Arduino side, I have serial input, which I can read from processing and store into an array.

I have created a class for each bar of a bar graph, however I want to make this scalable. If I have 100 bars on the bar graph, is there a way to make 100 different objects automatically?

Comment: Are you tring to do this ?
`for(int i=0; i<userInput;i++){ array[i] = new Object()}`

Comment: If you have 100 today, you'll have 1000 tomorrow. Better to use a List (that grows automatically). If you *really need* an array (unlikely and unwanted), you can easily get an array from a List

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is a perfect use for a [for loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html). In this case:

```
Object[] array = new Object[100];
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    array[i] = new Object();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [array](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arrays).

An array is a way of storing multiple instances in one value. So if you have a class named `Bar`, you can do this:

```
Bar[] bars = new Bar[100];
```

This creates an array called `bars`, which holds 100 indexes. Then you can treat each index as its own variable:

```
bars[0] = new Bar(42);
bars[1] = new Bar(67);
println(bars[0]);
println(bars[1]);
```

Where this becomes really useful is when you combine it with a counter or a `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   bars[i] = new Bar(whatever);
   println(bars[i]);
}
```

You can also use an [ArrayList](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/arraylists) which operates on a similar principle but allows you to easily add indexes over time.